# VM's IP address got changed. True?

Tags: ip-address, vmware

I just want to know whether a virtual machince IP address will change periodically. It was some xxx.xxx.xx.xx earlier and now after a month it is xxx.xxx.xx.xy. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

it depends from your dhcp server:
if dhcp server configured for leasing ip from a range, you can see all leased ips in 
dhcpd.leases file. 
If you want to use static ip's you can reserve ip from range and configure client machine for static ip using.

Comment: Thank a lot. Is there a way to find previous IP address of a VM? Or I have the previous IP address and is there any way to confirm that it was used earlier?